# Using dh_python2, how to build several debian packages with different python packages in them?

Tags: python, debian

I'm using a debian/rules file like `%: … dh $@ --with=python-central …`, which installs the python packages using setup.py; how can I modify it properly to place two of the python packages in one debian packages, and the rest of them in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that, as I have found out by too much poking around with strace, is:

- Two separate setup files (setup_firstpackage.py, setup_secondpackage.py)

  - Maybe a common `setup.py` that imports (and, thus, runs) both.
- Two packages from the same source packages in the `debian/control`
- Several overrides in debian/rules:

  - `override_dh_auto_build:` - disabled (see further)
  - `override_dh_auto_install:`

    - `python setup_firstpackage.py build --force -b build/firstpackage install --force --root=debian/firstpackage --no-compile -O0 --install-layout=deb`
    - `python setup_firstpackage.py build --force -b build/secondpackage install --force --root=debian/secondpackage --no-compile -O0 --install-layout=deb`
    - that's mostly the same as what auto_build and auto_install do, however with [chaining to use a cutom build directory](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2005-June/004669.html).
  - Funnily, dh_python needs no override and works just fine after that.
  - `override_dh_auto_clean:`

    - `rm -fr build/firstpackage build/secondpackage` – those don't get cleaned automatically. Could probably modify the paths for it to happen, though.
    - `dh_auto_clean`

Benefits:

- The separate package can be installed separately, of course (for example, if secondpackage depends on firstpackage, e.g. common libraries and a main app).
- The packages use the same changelog and versioning, which is very useful if they are often updated together.
- Packaging aside, it is possible to install the separate python app (e.g. useful if it has fewer dependencies) using its own setup file

  - Might not work quite well with pip though; it is probably better to at least make a common `setup.py` that imports both.